# How to create an interface that keeps some methods internal for testing in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interface, internal

Consider the following class

```
public class Entity {
  public void Foo() { ... }
  internal void Bar() { ... }
}
```

As you see it has a `public` method and an `internal` method. Now, I would like to create an interface which will allow me to mock this class in tests (both in this assembly and in others). I rewrite my code as following:

```
public interface IEntity {
  void Foo();
}

internal class Entity : IEntity {
  public void Foo() { ... }
  public void Bar() { ... }
}
```

However, this creates another issue. When using the class in another method in the same assembly I can't call `Bar` anymore:

```
public class OtherClass {
  public void SomeMethod(IEntity entity) {
    entity.Bar(); // error!
  }
}
```

Rewriting the code like this:

```
public class OtherClass {
  public void SomeMethod(IEntity entity) {
    (entity as Entity).Bar(); // error in test!
  }
}
```

will trigger an error in the unit test that triggers `SomeMethod`. How do I rewrite my code so that I can still use `internal` methods in the same assembly and yet only expose public members to other assemblies?

**Update:** Class `OtherClass` is a utility class that needs to operate on internals of the `Entity` class, which are not exposed to the users directly. However, this class itself is exposed to users, so they indirectly have access to internals of the `Entity`. This is desired as `SomeMethod` will perform necessary checks to ensure that users won't screw up the internal state of an `Entity` object.

Comment: Why don't you just make the methods virtual instead of creating an interface?

Comment: @adrianm: Because I also want a clear interface for the users, not mixed up with private/internal members and implementation. And also because I would like to be able to provide a different implementation in the future without rebuilding all dependent projects. However, considering all the difficulties, which interfaces create when dealing with internal members, I might choose this option despite the above advantages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edited:

Extend your `IEntity` interface with an internal `ITestEntity` interface for testing:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    //Implementation

}

internal interface ITestEntity : IEntity
{
    void TestMethod();
}


class Entity: ITestEntity
{
   //
}
```

Comment: This is a great idea, which came to my mind as well, but it doesn't work. To match your example to my question, `IEntity` will expose `Foo` and `ITestEntity` would expose `Bar`, which would require to pass internal `ITestEntity` to public `SomeMethod`. This causes inconsistent accessibility error.

Comment: I see. But if you pass around `IEntity`, You can cast to `ITestEntity` (you should mock `ITestEntity`), and use its methods. I admit it gets less elegant there.

Comment: This sounds right... users won't actually pass `Mock<IEntity>` into the `SomeMethod` as they won't write unit test for it. Instead they will only pass `Entity`. I think this may actually solve problem. Let's met test if this works and if so, I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: It worked. Since this is the closest to what I wanted - I'll mark the answer as accepted. However, I might actually end up making methods virtual as suggested by the comment to the question.

Answer (score 15):

> How do I rewrite my code so that I can still use internal methods in the same assembly and yet only expose public members to other assemblies?

Make the interface internal and then explicitly implement it.

```
internal interface ITest
{
  void Foo();
  void Bar();
}

public class Thing : ITest
{
  void ITest.Foo() { this.Foo(); }
  void ITest.Bar() { this.Bar(); }
  public Foo() { ... }
  internal Bar() { ... }
}
```

So now public class `Thing` has only one public method `Foo`. Code outside the assembly cannot call `Bar` either directly or via a conversion to the interface because `Bar` and `ITest` are both internal.

I note that a *base class* must be at least as visible as its deriving class. Not so interfaces. Few people know that this is legal:

```
class C : C.I
{
    private interface I {} 
}
```

A class can implement an interface that *only it can see*! This is a bit of a strange thing to do but there are some situations where it makes sense.

Comment: An interesting idea, but now users can't mock `Thing` class outside of the assembly. They may write classes using `Thing` and will probably want to unit-test them as well.

Comment: @SergiyByelozyorov: You can't have it both ways. Either `Bar` is accessible outside the assembly or it isn't.

Comment: It shouldn't be accessible outside. The users will only need to mock `Foo` as they don't even know about `Bar` existance.

Comment: I found this [blog](https://alexfranchuk.com/blog/internal-interface-classes-in-csharp/) is close to the answer here.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to call the internal method only in your unit tests right? Because otherwise, exposing the method to other assemblies would require to replace internal with public of cause.

For unit testing in general, it is always a good pattern if you DO NOT test private or internal methods. A Unit test should actually just test the public interface and any business class should provide public methods which do whatever internally...
So to test your internal methods, you would have to test the public representation of it.

But anyways. If you want to test private or internal accessor, Visual Studio Test projects usually can generate accessor wrappers for you. 
You would have to call the accessor ctor instead of the normal ctor of your class. When you do so, you can access any private or internal methods/properties of that instance.

Find more information about those generated types here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385974(v=vs.100).aspx

:edit: after discussion, I have an Example for you of how to use moq together with Unity and UnityAutoMoq (3 different Nugets).
Lets say your class looks like this:

```
public class MyClassWithInternalMethod
{
    internal object GetSomething()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

To test this you can mock it like this:

```
using (var moqUnityContainer = new UnityAutoMoqContainer())
{
    moqUnityContainer.GetMock<MyClassWithInternalMethod>().Setup(p => p.GetSomething()).Returns(null);
}
```

Comment: No. I want to call internal method in other methods in the same assembly as well, which are in turn public. And I am not trying to test internal method - I just want to mock it to make sure that some other class actually calls it.

Comment: did you try to use InternalsVisibleTo attribute?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx

Comment: I don't see how `InternalsVisibleTo` is helpful. I want to limit access to internals to the assembly, rather than giving access to other assemblies. This is so by default, but now I need to hide the class behind an interface for testing, which can't have internal access specifier.

Comment: Ok, to mock interfaces is not a good idea, usually you want to mock the concrete implementation. 
At runtime you inject the concrete class, your utility simply uses the interface.

Within your unit test, you'll have to construct your utility and use a mock of your concrete implementation and pass it to the utility constructor (or whatever injection you use...)
I currently use unity and the moq library to do this kind of stuff...
E.g. for testing classes which use logger, repositories etc...