# C# Calling internal methods of an object passed as interface

Tags: c#, interface

I have an interface IFoo defining some functions, an abstract class FooBase implementing IFoo and some internal functions, and several classes Foo deriving from FooBase.
I also have a class Bar that should call a method from FooBase but gets its parameters passed as IFoo. So everything looking like this:

```cs
public interface IFoo
{
  // Some methods
}

public abstract class FooBase : IFoo
{
  // Methods from IFoo

  internal TInternalType SomeMethod();
}

public class Foo1 : FooBase
{
  // ...
}

public class Bar
{
  public void DoSomething(IFoo foo)
  {
    // This does not feel right:
    TInternalType myT = (foo as FooBase).SomeMethod();
  }
}
```

As already said, this does not feel right, since anybody could come along, write a class Baz implementing IFoo and calling DoSomething with this will fail.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18943983) question/solution to a similar problem about internal stuff with public interfaces, but that won't change the problem that some third party class implementing IFoo would cause problems, i.e. i still have a lying API.

Alternatively i could change the type of DoSomething to take a parameter of type FooBase and secure FooBase from third party classes by making the constructor internal, but i want to have only abstractions in my public API, not implementations.

So in short i'm asking: Is there a way for a library to only expose abstractions (i.e. the user of the library is only working with those) but still access internal members?

Background:
I'm writing a library that exposes some types and uses another library L to implement its functionality. The fact that L is used, is an implementation detail that i want to hide from my library's users, so when at some point for some reason i have to replace L by something else, my users won't notice.

I now have some of these Foo classes that will be exposed to my users, and one Bar class that will work with L. For each class Foo, a respective instance of a class from L has to be created; but the separate Foo classes are too different, they each need individual logic to create their respective L class.

That's why i defined an internal abstract method in FooBase and each Foo is implementing its own method to generate its class from L, so Bar can just call this one method to gets what it needs to work with L.

Maybe there's a completely different approach than an internal overloaded method.

Comment: If you're relying on implementation from `FooBase` you should use that as your method parameter.

Comment: Use Reflection if you really want to, but take above comment to hart.

Comment: If your only concern is that `DoSomething` will fail for anything implementing `IFoo` but not inheriting from `FooBase`, then why not: `var probablyFooBase = foo as FooBase; if (probablyFooBase != null) { probablyFooBase.SomeMethod(); }`?

Comment: `"i want to have only abstractions in my public API, not implementations."` - well `FooBase` is an `abstract class` so your condition is still satisfied.

Comment: Does `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` work for your case (requires strongly signed assemblies)?

Comment: Note that there is existing well known case of special casing classes in similar way in .Net itself - some operations from `Enumerable` check what is passed in by `enumerableSource as IList` to change behavior of the method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of interfaces is to show the abilities of the implementation. If you need to access internal members of the implementation, you should let the consumers of the code know they are not really internal (either by following the other answers here, or for example with [**Interface Segregation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) and passing around only individual [**role interfaces**](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/RoleInterface.html)), or keep them really internal. In your case I think it should be encapsulated in the `FooBase` class.

I suppose that the `DoSomething` method also does other things to the `IFoo` implementation. Whatever `Bar` does with the internal type returned from the internal method should probably happen in `FooBase` in one of those other `IFoo` methods instead. The guiding principle here is [**Tell, don't ask**](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid exposing your base classes to the user, why not create another interface deriving from `IFoo`, calling it something like `IFooWithSomeMethod`, add a `SomeMethod` method to it, and implement that interface in `FooBase`?  Then `Bar.DoSomething` could take an `IFooWithSomeMethod` rather than a `IFoo`.

Btw, sorry for screwing up some of the names in the first pass.  Hopefully I've got it all straightened out now.

Comment: Whoops, i messed up. The reason, why SomeMethod should be internal is, that it returns an internal type. I edited my question.

Comment: Then how about making an interface that expresses the functionality you want from the internal type, deriving the internal type from that interface, and returning an instance of that interface from `SomeMethod`?

Comment: @C.Sura - crucial information. But still, if your only concern is, that `(foo as FooBase).SomeMethod();` might throw a NullReference exception, then why not simply check `if (foo is FooBase)` before? or are there other concerns?

Comment: The other concern is that there is no default behavior when it is not deriving from FooBase, i.e. DoSomething is not available; then i have to throw an exception anyway. - I'm actually depending on FooBase here, but i don't want to rely on this type in the API since it is already an implementation and not an abstraction. But if there is no other way, then i guess i'll have to change the parameter type to FooBase.

Answer (score 1):

If `FooBase` is a *special case* (and so you don't want decalare `IFooWithDoSomething`) that requires an additional call you can implement an *extension* to `IFoo`, something like that:

```
public static class FooExtensions {
  public static void DoSomething(this IFoo value) {
    FooBase special = value as FooBase;

    if (null != special)
      special.SomeMethod();
  }
}

public class Bar
{
  public void DoSomething(IFoo foo)
  {
    // Extension is called
    foo.SomeMethod();
  }
}
```