# What is the best way to refer to an object's internal implementation when working with interfaces?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, plugins, interface

I have a project that supports plugins. As to make plugins unit-testable, they only interact with the main application through interfaces.

The main application provides an implementation to these interfaces. The different components of this application also have dependencies between each others.

I want to limit the amount of interface members by only having the ones needed for plugin development. Problem is, sometimes an implementation needs to call a method that I do not want to expose to the plugins. In a "class" world, I would use the `internal` keyword for these methods.

Here's a rudimentary example that might be clearer:

```cs
interface IUserManager
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<IUser> Users { get; }
}

interface IUser
{
    string Name { get; }
}

class UserImpl : IUser
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public void Delete()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class UserManager : IUserManager
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<IUser> Users { get; }

    public void DeleteAllUsers()
    {
        foreach(var user in Users)
        {
            if(user is UserImpl impl)
            {
                impl.Delete();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Plugin
{
    public Plugin(IUserManager userManager)
    {
        // I want the plugin to be able to access the user's name, but not its Delete() method
        Console.WriteLine(userManager.Users.First().Name);
    }
}

class NetworkController
{
    private readonly IUserManager _userManager;
    public ReceiveDeleteMessage(string name)
    {
        var user = _userManager.Users.Single(x => x.Name == name);
        user.Delete(); // not possible, needs a cast
    }
}
```

But this feels wrong to me... Not only we now have a cast that could fail, we have no way to mock the Delete() function for implementation unit tests. The best thing I could come with is adding an "internal" interface, but I am still stuck with the cast.

```cs
interface IInternalUser : IUser
{
    void Delete();
}

class UserImpl : IInternalUser
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public void Delete()
    {
    }
}

// in UserManager ...
if(user is IInternalUser internalUser)
{
    internalUser.Delete();
}
```

I could settle with this and I think it will be fine, but this little detail makes me feel like I am not taking the best approach. I am looking for better ideas on how to do this.

Comment: IUser like a data , not a behavior , so not good to test.

Comment: maybe IReadOnlyCollection<IUserBehavior> Users { get; } is better

Comment: similar (but with no satisfying answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18943983/how-to-create-an-interface-that-keeps-some-methods-internal-for-testing-in-c/18944374#18944374

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce an interface `IUserWithDelete` such as:

```
interface IUserWithDelete: IUser
{
    void Delete();
}
```

This interface will not be passed to any plugins, thus they will never see the `Delete()` method.

Then class `UserManager` can have an `IReadOnlyCollection<IUserWithDelete>` field that it exposes as `IReadOnlyCollection<IUser>`.

The `UserImpl` class would implement `IUserWithDelete`, and `UserImpl` can be internal if you want.

So you would implement `UserImpl` like so:

```
class UserImpl : IUserWithDelete
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public void Delete()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And class `UserManager` along the lines of:

```
class UserManager : IUserManager
{
    public UserManager(IReadOnlyCollection<IUserWithDelete> users)
    {
        _users = users;
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<IUser> Users => _users;

    public void DeleteAllUsers()
    {
        foreach (var user in _users)
        {
            user.Delete();
        }
    }

    readonly IReadOnlyCollection<IUserWithDelete> _users;
}
```

No casting is required, and the plugins only see `Users` as `IReadOnlyCollection<IUser>` and thus `IUserWithDelete` is not exposed to them.

[Example on .net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1rv6CZ)

---

To answer your amended question:

Firstly, I think that the delete operation should be in the user manager class - after all, that's its job!

Secondly, doing it that way you can introduce another new interface, `IUserManagerWithDelete` (which can be internal if the implementation of NetworkController is internal) like so:

```
interface IUserManagerWithDelete: IUserManager
{
    bool DeleteUser(string name);
}
```

Then your `UserManager` implementation becomes:

```
class UserManager : IUserManagerWithDelete
{
    public UserManager(IReadOnlyCollection<IUserWithDelete> users)
    {
        _users = users;
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<IUser> Users => _users;

    public bool DeleteUser(string name)
    {
        var user = _users.SingleOrDefault(user => user.Name == name);
        user?.Delete();
        return user != null;
    }

    public void DeleteAllUsers()
    {
        foreach (var user in _users)
        {
            user.Delete();
        }
    }

    readonly IReadOnlyCollection<IUserWithDelete> _users;
}
```

And the internal class `NetworkController` something like:

```
class NetworkController
{
    public NetworkController(IUserManagerWithDelete userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public bool ReceiveDeleteMessage(string name)
    {
        return _userManager.DeleteUser(name);
    }

    readonly IUserManagerWithDelete _userManager;
}
```

Note that for illustrative purposes, I've made the return type of `DeleteUser()` a `bool` to indicate whether the user was actually deleted (but it will still throw an exception if more than one user with the same name is in the list).

Comment: `public IReadOnlyCollection<IUser> Users => _users;` would require a cast

`public IReadOnlyCollection<IUser> Users => _users.Cast<IUser>().ToList().AsReadOnly();`

we end up with the same issue or even worse since we now have two different collections

Comment: @Romain No, it does not require a cast. `IReadOnlyCollection` is covariant. Try it! Or look at the .net Fiddle example I posted a link to.

Comment: Oh you are right, it does work! Now the only issue left is that I want another class (in the same assembly as the implementation) to call that Delete() method, from a IUserManager... I added a NetworkController class to my example

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, your solution for the manager is great. In the meantime I've posted something else I figured out as an answer, is there anything wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution going further with @matthew-watson's answer

```cs
public interface IInternalUserManager : IUserManager
{
    new IReadOnlyCollection<IUserWithDelete> Users { get; }
}

public class UserManager : IInternalUserManager
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<IUserWithDelete> Users => _users;
    IReadOnlyCollection<IUser> IUserManager.Users => _users;
}
```

This allows me to inject IInternalUserManager to NetworkController, while using the same object as an IUserManager in the plugin's container without having duplicate property names for the same collection.

Comment: You will have to make `IUserWithDelete` public rather than internal for that to work, but if that's acceptable then this will work. Also note that now `UserManager` is exposing a public `IReadOnlyCollection<IUserWithDelete>` compared to the other solution where it only has a public `IReadOnlyCollection<IUser>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface IDelete 
{
    void Delete();
}

interface IUser : IDelete
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

like this ?

```
interface IUserBehavior : IDelete , ICreate ....
{
    IUser Data;
}

IReadOnlyCollection<IUserBehavior> Users { get; }
```

or this ?

Comment: No, I don't want IUser to have the delete method

Comment: The Users collection is also tied to the IUser interface. It must be a IReadOnlyCollection<IUser>. I updated my main post with a plugin example